# URL detection from Image

Tags: python, computer-vision, google-vision

I have some images that include several kinds of URLs, and I am trying to convert it into text and extract boundary box. I've tried to use google vision and it performs well on short URLs, but it usually ignore the whole long URL. I guess it is because long URL is considered to be non-English string. Is there any way to improve this problem?

Here is an example:

[image]

Basically, the code just sending the image to Google vision.
Then drawing the boundary box (vertices) to image.

```
from google.cloud import vision
import io

path = "test3.jpg"
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, "rb") as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
texts = response.text_annotations

# Draw boundary box
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

figure(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=80)

im = Image.open(path)

for text in texts:
    vects = text.bounding_poly.vertices
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.polygon(
        [vects[0].x, vects[0].y, vects[1].x, vects[1].y, vects[2].x, vects[2].y, vects[3].x, vects[3].y], None, "red"
    )

plt.imshow(im)
plt.savefig("output.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please paste some code what you have done . So that we can understand where you stuck exactly !

Comment: I would try running an OCR application over the image and then trying a regex search on the result to see if there was a valid url in the image.